# Howto run kubectl from snap package?

Tags: snap, kubernetes

By example:

```bsh
$ sudo snap install kubectl --classic;
$ kubectl cluster-info dump;
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
$ ps -aux | grep kube;
$ lsb_release -a;
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Need install other package o service?, i try install `kubeadm`:

```bsh
$ sudo snap install kubeadm --classic;
$ sudo kubeadm init;
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.20.4
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING Service-Docker]: docker service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable docker.service'
...
$ sudo snap services;
Servicio        Encendido  Actual    Notas
docker.dockerd  activado   activo    -
kubelet.daemon  activado   inactivo  -
$ sudo docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build cd8016b6bc
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading from the Ubuntu Software Center rather than the terminal. I see it's available in my 20.02.2

Comment: In theory it should be exactly the same, the ubuntu snap software center does not install additional packages to the necessary ones.

Answer (score 0):

edit /etc/systemd/system/snap.docker.dockerd.service (or other snap docker service location) adding the following row:

```
[Install]
Alias=docker.service
```

then run:

```
sudo systemctl reenable snap.docker.dockerd.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart snap.docker.dockerd.service
```

in my case it worked.

hth